# 422 Not returning send message(Node.js/Redux)

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, axios, http-error

I am having an issue where my node.js server is returning a 422 to the browser with a message but the browser is just seeing the 422 and nothing with it.

```
//Node.js 
if (existingUser) {
 return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Email is in use' });
}
```

I can confirm it is hitting there and returning at that point

```
//Redux method
export function signupUser({ email, password }) {
 return function(dispatch) {
  return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signup`, { email, password })
   .then(response => {
    dispatch(emailWasSent(response.data.return_msg));
   })
   .catch(response => {
    dispatch(authError(response.data.error));});
  }
}
```

It will hit the catch but the response only contains 422

```
//Console.log of response
Error: Request failed with status code 422
```

Comment: Could you show us code that is doing logging?

Comment: The code that is doing the logging is the redux catch part

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for a day I found out it is an axios issue. They changed their catch case. It should now be

```
error.response.data.error
```